# Overwriting watchers or check statement inside function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am newbie in JavaScript (using JQuery) and creating JQuery's watchers for fixed header (hide on scroll down, show on scroll up) + resize watcher to make it mobile-orientation friendly.

Should I use:

```
var
    $window = $( window ),
    minWindowHeight = ( $window.height() >= ( $( 'header' ) * 5 ) );

// Init when page opened
if ( minWindowHeight ) {
    $window.scroll(function(event){
        // Set setInterval 250 to function (avoid too often funtion call)
        //   -> the function
    });
}

// When browser window resized (for example mobile orientation)
$window.resize(function(event){
    minWindowHeight = ( $window.height() >= ( $( 'header' ) * 5 ) );

    if ( minWindowHeight ) {
        $window.scroll(function(event){
            // Set setInterval 250 to function (avoid too often funtion call)
            //   -> the function
        });
    }
});
```

Or

```
var
    $window = $( window ),
    minWindowHeight = ( $window.height() >= ( $( 'header' ) * 5 ) );

// Init when page opened
$window.scroll(function(event){

    // Set setInterval 250 to function (avoid too often funtion call)
        //   -> the function start
            if ( minWindowHeight ) {
                // do something
            }
        //   -> the function end
});

// When browser window resized (for example mobile orientation)
$window.resize(function(event){
    minWindowHeight = ( $window.height() >= ( $( 'header' ) * 5 ) );
});
```

Or maybe completely another kind of watchers or something?

Also answer with tutorial explaining exactly such things will be great - I have no idea for what keywords search.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all you should consider to use media query to make your page mobile friendly, if it's impossible to complete with css, then you should use jQuery :)

Comment: Yes, I have my site builded on media queries, but in this case I would make fixed header only if window height is at least 5 times heigher - on landscape orientation it's annoying, because takes ~40% of screen, but on portrait it's only ~15%.

Comment: Ah, I forgot write that I am using JQuery to fixed header because it's hides on scroll down and shows on scroll up.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case i advise you to declare a function to minimise those big calls of same variable

```
var win = $(window),
header = $("header");

(function($){
  function gapCalc (win,header){
    return ( $(win).height() >= ( $(header).height()*5 ) );
  }
}(jQuery));

$(window).resize(function(){
  if(gapCalc(win,header)){
    //do something
  }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  if(gapCalc(win,header)){
    //do something
  }
});
```

Comment: But in `//do something` I need to include `scroll` event, so your solution still let me in unknown. I just want use `scroll` event if `minWindowHeight` statement met.